# How to format the axis label using MVC Chart Helper and razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

As a training exercise I'm converting a weather data application I wrote from webforms to MVC5.  I was able to convert my entire application to MVC with the exception of the graph page.  My old application used ZedGraph.  For the new application I'm trying to use the Chart helper, but I can't seem to figure out how to format the axis label.  The data is coming from a list of WeatherData objects that have a Date property which I'd like to display as a time.

Is there any way to format the label?

I figure worst case I can add a new property to WeatherData to format the date, but that goes against the separation of display logic from business logic.

```
@{ 
var myChart = new Chart(width: 700, height: 400)
    .AddTitle(ViewBag.Station)
    .AddSeries("Maximum wind speed", chartType: "line",
        xValue: Model.data, xField: "Date",
        yValues: Model.data, yFields: "MaximumWindspeed")
    .AddSeries("Average wind speed", chartType: "line",
        xValue: Model.data, xField: "Date",
        yValues: Model.data, yFields: "AverageWindspeed")
    .Write();
}
```

[Example Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMRcu.jpg)

Comment: *The data is coming from a list of WeatherData objects that have a Date property*.. so just to be clear.. those objects aren't `DateTime` objects? They don't have any *time* associated with them? I would imagine they do since there are different plots on the chart

Comment: The WeatherData object contains weather data at a specific observation. One of the properties is a DateTime object (named Date) containing the date and time of that observation.

Comment: Do you have any format for that `DateTime` object in your Model?

Comment: What I did to make this work is to add a new property to the WeatherData class that returns the DateTime object as a string with a time format.  While this solved my problem, I'd prefer not to have to add formatting to my data object since this is something that should be done preferably in the view.